# Using ARRAY_AGG() with DISTINCT and ORDER BY with ORDINAL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some data that I am trying to aggregate (greatly simplified here). The raw data uses a schema similar to the following:

```
UserID - STRING
A - RECORD REPEATED
A.Action - STRING
A.Visit - INTEGER
A.Order - INTEGER
MISC - RECORD REPEATED
( other columns omitted here )
```

There are many actual records due to the "MISC" column, but I'm only trying to focus on the first 5 columns shown above. A sample of the raw data is shown below (note that the values shown are a sample only, many other values exist so these cannot be hard coded into the query) :

**Table 0: (Raw data sample)**

(empty values under UserID are as shown in BiqQuery - "A" fields are part of a nested record)

[image: Table0]

My query produces the data shown in **Table 1** below. I am trying to use ARRAY_AGG with ORDINAL to select only the first two "Action"s for each user and restructure as shown in TABLE 2.

```
SELECT
  UserId, ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT(A.Action, A.Visit, A.Order)
          ORDER BY A.Visit, A.Order, A.Action ) 
  FROM
    `table` 
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(A) AS A
GROUP BY
    UserId
```

**Table 1: (Sample output of above query )**

[image: Table1]

**Table 2: (The format needed)**

[image: Table2]

So I need to:

1. Get distinct "Action" values for each user
2. Preserve the order ( UserID, Visit, Order )
3. Show only the 1st and 2nd actions in one row

My attempted query strategy was to ORDER BY UserID, Visit, Order and get DISTINCT values of Action using something like:

```
UserId,
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Action ORDER BY UserID, Visit, Order) FirstAction,
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Action ORDER BY UserID, Visit, Order) SecondAction
```

However, that approach produces the following error:

> Error: An aggregate function that has both DISTINCT and ORDER BY arguments can only ORDER BY columns that are arguments to the function

Any thoughts on how to correct this error (or an alternative approach?)

Comment: I think you'll need to compute the distinct actions in a subquery first, then use ARRAY_AGG with ORDER BY.

Comment: why is the second action for U0003 empty, and not Share?

Comment: There will be some cases where a second action has not yet occurred (new user).

Comment: but the sample data shows the second action for U0003 was Share

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up note Felipe, you are correct and I updated Table 1 above.

Comment: Mikhail, thanks for the tips - I'm relatively new on this forum so I'll check out the docs you suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure why the original query has `DISTINCT`, if the results shown in table 2 don't need de-duplication.

With that said:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT actor.login userid, type action
    , EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) visit
    , EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM created_at) `order`
  FROM `githubarchive.day.20171005` 
)

SELECT userid, actions[OFFSET(0)] firstaction, actions[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] secondaction
FROM (
  SELECT userid, ARRAY_AGG(action ORDER BY visit, `order` LIMIT 2) actions
  FROM sample
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1
  LIMIT 100
)
```

[image]

Comment: Felipe, thank you for your suggestions.  I added "Table 0" and a clarification above it that speaks to the duplicates per your question above. I tried your approach, which seems to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT UserId, 
  ARRAY_AGG(Action ORDER BY Visit, `Order`, Action LIMIT 2)[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS FirstAction, 
  ARRAY_AGG(Action ORDER BY Visit, `Order`, Action LIMIT 2)[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS SecondAction 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(A) AS A 
GROUP BY UserId
-- ORDER BY UserId
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT 'U001' AS UserId, [STRUCT<Action STRING, Visit INT64, `Order` INT64 >
    ('Register', 1, 1),('Upgrade', 1, 2),('Feedback', 1, 3),('Share', 1, 4),('Share', 2, 1)] AS A UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U002', [STRUCT<Action STRING, Visit INT64, `Order` INT64 >
    ('Share', 7, 1),('Share', 7, 2),('Refer', 8, 1),('Feedback', 8, 2),('Feedback', 8, 3)] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U003', [STRUCT<Action STRING, Visit INT64, `Order` INT64 >
    ('Register', 1, 1),('Share', 1, 2),('Share', 1, 3),('Share', 2, 1),('Share', 2, 2),('Share', 3, 1),('Share', 3, 2)] 
)
SELECT UserId, 
  ARRAY_AGG(Action ORDER BY Visit, `Order`, Action LIMIT 2)[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS FirstAction, 
  ARRAY_AGG(Action ORDER BY Visit, `Order`, Action LIMIT 2)[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS SecondAction 
FROM `table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(A) AS A 
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY UserId
```

Comment: did you have chance to try this?did it worked for you? it should :o)

Comment: I'm actually trying it now... just posted another clarification above (Table 0 and the note above it). The values for "Register", "Upgrade", "Feedback" etc. must all be pulled from the data (cannot be hard coded as you have it above). So I'm trying to figure out a way to adapt your suggestions.

Comment: this is just example!! remove with statement and use your real table! see update! try and let me know

Comment: Mikhail, yes thanks for the clarification - I tried it and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Brain teasing question: can we build an array with only distinct elements by using `ARRAY_AGG`?

Comment: sure, possible! post your specific question if you have problem making it work